# Function call only works if called once

Tags: arduino-nano, c++, led

I have 3 LED chains which are all mapped to concentric rings. Each ring has a its own 2D array with the chain number & LED number. I have a function that is passed a ring array and then lights the appropriate LED. I'm using `FastLED`

```
void lightUp(int ring_arr[][2], int i, int col){
  
  if(ring_arr[i][0] == 0){
      L0[ring_arr[i][1]] = CHSV(col, 255, 255);
    }
    if(ring_arr[i][0] == 1){
      L1[ring_arr[i][1]] = CHSV(col, 255, 255);
    }
    if(ring_arr[i][0] == 2){
      L2[ring_arr[i][1]] = CHSV(col, 255, 255);
  }
}
```

This works fine BUT only if its called once in `loop()` if I make a 2nd call none of the LEDs light up. So I can light up 1 ring at a time but if I try to light up 2 or more then nothing lights up. Anyone see anything obvious that I'm overlooking?

The full code listing,

```
#include <FastLED.h>

#define NELEMS(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))
#define DATA_0 5
#define DATA_1 6
#define DATA_2 7
#define NUM_LEDS 50 

CRGB L0[NUM_LEDS];
CRGB L1[NUM_LEDS];
CRGB L2[NUM_LEDS];

// Rings
int ring_1[][2] = {{0,0}, {0,1},  {0,2},  {0,3},  {1,49}, 
                   {1,28}, {1,29}, {1,30}, {1,31}, {1,32},
                   {1,23}, {1,24}, {1,25}, {1,26}, {1,27},
                   {1,2},  {1,3},  {1,4},  {1,5},  {1,6},
                   {1,0},  {1,1},  {2,0},  {2,1},  {2,2}, 
                   {2,19}, {2,20}, {2,21}, {2,22}, {2,23},
                   {2,24}, {2,25}, {2,26}, {2,27}, {2,28},
                   {2,45}, {2,46}, {2,47}, {2,48}, {2,49},
                   {0,29}, {0,28}, {0,27}, {0,26}, {0,25},
                   {0,4},  {0,5},  {0,6},  {0,7},  {0,8}};
                  
int ring_2[][2] = {{1,48}, {1,33}, {1,22}, {1,7},  {2,3}, 
                   {2,18}, {2,29}, {2,44}, {0,24}, {0,9}};

int ring_3[][2] = {{1,47}, {1,34}, {1,21}, {1,8},  {2,4},
                   {2,17}, {2,30}, {2,43}, {0,23}, {0,10}};

int ring_4[][2] = {{1,46}, {1,35}, {1,20}, {1,9}, {2,5}, 
                   {2,16}, {2,31}, {2,42}, {0,22}, {0,11}};

int ring_5[][2] = {{1,45}, {1,36}, {1,19}, {1,10}, {2,6}, 
                   {2,15}, {2,32}, {2,41}, {0,21}, {0,12}};

int ring_6[][2] = {{1,44}, {1,37}, {1,18}, {1,11}, {2,7}, 
                   {2,14}, {2,33}, {2,40}, {0,20}, {0,13}};

int ring_7[][2] = {{1,43}, {1,38}, {1,17}, {1,12}, {2,8}, 
                   {2,13}, {2,34}, {2,39}, {0,19}, {0,14}};

int ring_8[][2] = {{1,42}, {1,39}, {1,16}, {1,13}, {2,9}, 
                   {2,12}, {2,35}, {2,38}, {0,18}, {0,15}};
                   
int ring_9[][2] = {{1,41}, {1,40}, {1,15}, {1,14}, {2,10}, 
                   {2,11}, {2,36}, {2,37}, {0,17}, {0,16}};
// Colours
int col_1 = 0;
int col_2 = 160;
int col_3 = 96;


void setup(){
  
   // LED set up
   FastLED.addLeds<WS2811,DATA_0,RGB>(L0, NUM_LEDS);
   FastLED.addLeds<WS2811,DATA_1,RGB>(L1, NUM_LEDS);
   FastLED.addLeds<WS2811,DATA_2,RGB>(L2, NUM_LEDS);
   FastLED.setBrightness(255); 
   clearAll();
}

void loop() 
{

  for(int i; i < NELEMS(ring_1); i++){
    lightUp(ring_1, i, col_1);
  }

  for(int i; i < NELEMS(ring_2); i++){
    
//    lightUp(ring_2, i, col_2); // if I uncomment any of these
//    lightUp(ring_3, i, col_3); // no LEDs light up
//    lightUp(ring_4, i, col_1); 
//    lightUp(ring_5, i, col_2);
//    lightUp(ring_6, i, col_3);
//    lightUp(ring_7, i, col_1);
//    lightUp(ring_8, i, col_2);
//    lightUp(ring_9, i, col_3);
    
  }

  FastLED.show();
  delay(1000);
}

void clearAll(){
  for(int i; i < NUM_LEDS; i++){
    L0[i] = CHSV(0, 0, 0);
    L1[i] = CHSV(0, 0, 0);
    L2[i] = CHSV(0, 0, 0);
  }
  FastLED.show();
}

void lightUp(int ring_arr[][2], int i, int col){
  
  if(ring_arr[i][0] == 0){
      L0[ring_arr[i][1]] = CHSV(col, 255, 255);
    }
    if(ring_arr[i][0] == 1){
      L1[ring_arr[i][1]] = CHSV(col, 255, 255);
    }
    if(ring_arr[i][0] == 2){
      L2[ring_arr[i][1]] = CHSV(col, 255, 255);
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you run the first `for` loop twice?

Comment: @jsotola no LEDs light up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for` loops are missing an initialization. You should write

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < NELEMS(ring_1); i++)
```

but you missed the `= 0` part. This means the `i` variable ends up
uninitialized, and contains whatever was left in this memory location by
whatever used that memory before. The behavior in such situation is
generally unpredictable. However, one may guess that the `i` of the
second loop could be allocated in the same spot as the `i` of the first
loop. If this happens, then the second loop starts at `i=3` and ends up
being an empty loop.

As a (completely unrelated) side note, you could gather your three `L*`
arrays into a single 2D array. This would make `lightUp()` significantly
simpler:

```cpp
void lightUp(int ring_arr[][2], int i, int col) {
    L[ring_arr[i][0]][ring_arr[i][1]] = CHSV(col, 255, 255);
}
```

or maybe it would be clearer like this:

```cpp
void lightUp(int *location, int col) {
    L[location[0]][location[1]] = CHSV(col, 255, 255);
}
```

To be called as `lightUp(ring_1[i], col_1);`.

Comment: Let this be a lesson for people who flit between Python & C++ too often. Also why did the question get a downvote?